# Insertar Cada registro de un datagridview a base de datos visual studio 2015?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015

tengo una gran duda acerca de...
¿Cómo hacer que me haga múltiples insert a mi base de datos los registros que están dentro de mi datagridview?.

por ejemplo: Un viaje de tal fecha, insertar todas las personas que irán a ese viaje, en este caso serian todos los que estén en mi datagridview.

He estado probando con **For** y  **datagridview.RowCount** pero sin éxito alguno.

Desde ya muchas gracias!!!.

Comment: El loop del datagridview te funciona? O el problema es sólo a nivel de la query. Pon el código para que lo veamos.

Comment: pues bueno estoy haciendo pruebas con un textbox para que me vaya mostrando los nombres de las personas que estan en el datagrid y nada aun.

        Dim fila As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow


        For Each fila In dgv_retiro.Rows
            nombre = fila.Cells(1).Value

            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(nombre)
        Next

Answer (score 0):

Recorre el DataGridView y ve recogiendo los valores a tu gusto.

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In BOM.dvg_retiro.Rows
  For i = 0 To row.Cells.Count - 1
      nombre = fila.Cells(i).Value 
      TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(nombre) 
  Next
Next
```

Te dejo un enlace donde puedes verlo mejor: [Loop through DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777205/looping-through-datagridview)

Comment: mmm puse esto 

  For istep As Integer = 0 To dgv_retiro.RowCount - 2
            TextBox1.Text = dgv_retiro.Item(1, istep).Value

        Next

y lo que obtuve solo fue el ultimo registro del datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Sergio,

Te dejo el código con un `For Each` recorriendo todas las filas de la DataGridView para insertar los datos en tu base de datos abriendo sólo la conexión una vez:

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection("cadena_conexión")
    Using cm As New SqlCommand()
        cm.Connection = cn
        cn.Open()
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dvg_retiro.Rows
            cm.CommandText = " INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (" & _
                dr.Cells("nombre_columna1").Value & "," & dr.Cells("nombre_columna2").Value & "," & dr.Cells("nombre_columna3").Value & ")"
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
        cn.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: probare esta amigo! se ve prometedora jeje

Comment: el código esta bien, ahora bueno el problema es que el insert no quiero que solo sea de los datos del datagrid si no que de otras cosas... por así decir la fecha, al poner la fecha del datetimepicker en los value del query me dice que no existe esa columna y con mucha razón. En ese caso como haría?

Comment: Muestrame como lo pones en la query, te deberia quedar algo asi:
cm.CommandText = " INSERT INTO nombre_tabla (col1, col2, col3) VALUES (" & _
                fechaDateTimePicker.Value & "," & dr.Cells("nombre_columna2").Value & "," & dr.Cells("nombre_columna3").Value & ")"

Comment: Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.conxion)
            Using cm As New SqlCommand()
                cm.Connection = cn
                cn.Open()
                For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgv_retiro.Rows
                    cm.CommandText = " INSERT INTO retiros (cod_persona, fec_retiro,nom_evento) VALUES (" & dr.Cells("codigo").Value & "," & Retiros.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString & "," & Retiros.txt_evento.Text & ")"
                    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
                cn.Close()
            End Using
        End Using

Comment: @SergioAguiriano Te recomiendo que lo plantees en otra pregunta a la comunidad, ya que se puede alargar mucho los comentarios y ésta duda nueva que te surge no entra dentro de la pregunta principal del post, de ésta manera puedes añadir más código y obtener ayuda de más gente.

Comment: @SergioAguiriano Si tienes una respuesta definitiva, marcala para dar la pregunta como respondida

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada debes entender que un `DataGridView` es un control y como tal tiene propiedades donde cada propiedad es para un propósito distinto.

El Intellicense de Visual studio 2015 no recuerdo si estaba tan bien formalizado como el de visual studio 2017 y 2019 así que recomiendo que actualices el IDE a la versión mas reciente. Por otra parte la propiedad `RowCount` del control `DataGridView` sirve para contar las Rows que se tiene cargado el `DataGridView` por lo cual te sirva para recorrer un for pero no para hacer todo lo que necesitas. Asi que vamos a ir por partes para no marearte.

> Paso 1

Identificar cual es el problema y que solución logica se le puede dar con las herramientas que el lenguaje nos brinda, por cierto...No especificaste que lenguaje estas usando, supondré que estas programando en `C#` aunque esta respuesta valdra para `VB.net` también.

> El problema

Necesitamos recorrer un DataGridView para extraer informacion de fila por fila, celda por celda y cargarla en una base de datos, que por cierto... no especificaste que tipo de base de datos es por lo que supondre que estas trabajando con MySql aunque vale también para Access la respuesta que daré.

> La solucion (Tecnica)

Obtendremos la cantidad total de `Rows`(Filas) que compone nuestro control `DataGridView` al que llamaremos como `_DataGV` y recorreremos fila por fila y guardarlos en la base de datos de MySql mediante una query en lenguaje SQL llamada `INSERT`. Como no tengo datos de cual es el esquema de tu tabla pondre una tabla generica con valores genericos para que luego adaptes lo mismo a tu tabla.

> La solucion (Logica)

```
void CargarDatos(DataGridView _DataGV)
    {

        static public string path = "Tu connection string";
        static public MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(path);

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn.ConnectionString = path;
            conn.Open();
        }

        string Valor1;
        string Valor2;

        //Recorremos con un foreach cada fila del datagridview
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in _DataGV.Rows)
        {
            //Asignamos el valor obtenido de la primer y segunda del datagridview
            Valor1 = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            Valor2 = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            //Creamos la coneccion 

            MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            //Aplicamos POO ya ser mas ordenanos
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tu_tabla (Valor1, Valor2) VALUES(@Valor1, @Valor2)";
            //Indexamos los los datos
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor1", Valor1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Valor2", Valor2);
            //Ejecutamos la query
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }
        //Cerramos la conexión al terminar el foreach
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Cualquier duda o inconveniente respondo rápido.